# Mongoosejs: combining two 'query.where' clauses with 'or'

Tags: mongoose

I have a mongoosejs `Query`, which I am trying to execute.

I have:

```
query.where('loc').nearSphere(loc).maxDistance(range/6378.137);
query.where('name', name );
```

I want to combine the two queries without using `this.find( $or: {} )`.

The code is supposed to either find a document where the location is within a range, or the name matches the name provided.

Is it possible to create the query using `query.or()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

```
query.or([
    {
        nearSphere: 'loc',
        near: loc,
        maxDistance: (range/6378.137) },
    {
        "name": name
    }
]);
```

The part I couldn't understand was how to embed a query inside the `$or` clause.

I thought of deleting the question, but I left it here with this solution in case it's ever helpful to someone

Comment: This is not allowed since Mongoose 2.6 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-and-geospatial-queries